# Solutions for $(x)_n+(y)_n+(z)_n=(30)_n$ for odd $x,y,z$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

Suppose we choose $x,y,z$  from $\left\{1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15\right\}$ are there any solutions for $$x+y+z=30$$

It is obvious that adding three odd numbers is never an even number. So this equation does not have $\color{red} {\text{a  solution}}$ .
now change the point of view : 
 If we change base of numbers for example taking $7$ vs $10$ natural base . one solution is $$\color{red} {(11)_7+(11)_7+(5)_7=(30)_7}$$ 
$$(7+1)+(7+1)+5=21=(30)_7 \color{blue}{\checkmark}$$
now my question : Are there any more solution ,or a method to find other solutions like this...
I am thankful for your hint ,guide or any solution  In advanced.

Comment: I suggest that you improve your title. In particular, the "Funny Question:" part could be removed, or at least without color.

Comment: The base will clearly be odd here.  Another solution is $(11)_5+(11)_5+3=(30)_5$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the new title does not respect the original spirit of the question. I think you are not thinking of *odd* numbers, but to numbers that *seem* odd if though as expressed in base ten, but that are expressed in another base. Looking at your example in base $7$, you use $(11)_7$ which is in fact an even number. I think it is not hard to find solutions like yours, you just have to take care that you cannot use all of the elements of the set you have given: for instance "$9$" is not a valid number in base $7$. A few solutions I found in zero time (I chose an odd base, I started with $(11)_n$ which is even, I added a bigger even number, and then found the last needed odd number; but there are other strategies):

$$(13)_9 + (11)_9 + (5)_9 = (30)_9$$
$$(15)_9 + (11)_9 + (3)_9 = (30)_9$$
$$(13)_7 + (11)_7 + (3)_7 = (30)_7$$
$$(13)_5 + (11)_5 + (1)_5 = (30)_5$$
$$(13)_{11} + (11)_{11} + (7)_{11} = (30)_{11}$$

If you instead want to really use odd numbers, it is even easier to find a lot of solutions. Think of the easiest (in any odd base $\gt 3$): $(10)_n + (10)_n + (10)_n =(30)_n$. Then you can move around even numbers at will, e.g. $(10+2)_n + (10-2)_n + (10)_n =(30)_n$.